# Prevent form data from submitting after http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

The following code prevents submitting the form data

```
$('#dataForm').submit(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

My problem is how to achieve that in case there's an ajax call which takes time to get response.
So the form will not wait until the request get the response

```
$('#dataForm').submit(function (e) {
  ajaxCallAsPromise().then(function (data){
     if (data == true)
       {
         e.preventDefault(); //this will not work
       }
  });
  //any codes here works normally ..
});
```

My purpose to wait until get the request response then use-

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to call `preventDefault()` immediately to stop the form submission. There's no way to avoid that as the AJAX call is asynchronous and you'll need to wait for it.

However you can call `submit()` on the form element itself after the AJAX call completes in order to subvert the jQuery event handler and allow the form to be sent to the server, like this:

```js
$('#dataForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
  var form = this;

  ajaxCallAsPromise().then(function(data) {
    if (!data) { // if data is verified, submit the form again
      form.submit();
    } else {
      // presumably you want to tell the user the data is invalid here...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: in case this line 

- form.submit();

it will recall the whole function again which first line is e.preventDefault() , right ?

Comment: No. It's calling the `submit` event on the `form` directly. jQuery won't listen for that event.

Comment: Thanks so much - I'll try your answer , then accept it

Comment: after this line - form.submit(); , this output empty array , however the form has submitted data -> $(this).serializeArray()

Comment: I don't understand what you mean